# C++ How can I convert wchar_t* to TCHAR [] (not TCHAR*)

Tags: c++, tchar

I wants to add a small additional options to a big unit, so I do not want to process a large amount of code.

```
TCHAR szTempFileName[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR lpTempPathBuffer[MAX_PATH];
int uRetVal = 0;
GetTempPath(MAX_PATH,          // length of the buffer
    lpTempPathBuffer); // buffer for path 
GetTempFileName(lpTempPathBuffer, // directory for tmp files
    TEXT("QRCode_"),     // temp file name prefix 
    0,                // create unique name 
    szTempFileName);  // buffer for name
```

I want to change szTempFileName to optional wstring/std::string/wchar_t* parametr .

Solution:

1. change TCHAR to wchar_t
2. wcscpy(wchar_t[], wchat_t*);

Comment: It makes no sense to change a `wchat_t*` to a `TCHAR` and a `TCHAR` is a single character where the `wchat_t*` can be many.  Do note that a `TCHAR[]` and a `TCHAR*` are interchangeable for the most part.

Comment: Do you mean you only want a single character from the wide-character string?

Comment: No my mistake, I try to convert wchar_t* to TCHAR[] 
    wchar_t* w = L"somewchart";
    TCHAR t = ....

Answer (score 0):

Typically, there's no reason to use `TCHAR`s at all. If you're working with `wchar_t` anyway, simply call the [Unicode variants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089(v=vs.85).aspx) of the Winapi functions directly by adding a `W` suffix:

```
// Use wchar_t instead of TCHAR.
wchar_t szTempFileName[MAX_PATH];
wchar_t lpTempPathBuffer[MAX_PATH];
int uRetVal = 0;
// Call GetTempPathW directly.
GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH, lpTempPathBuffer);
// Use L"..." instead of TEXT("...").
GetTempFileNameW(lpTempPathBuffer, L"QRCode_", 0, szTempFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick with what you have and convert to the appropriate string type at the end. Getting windows to play nicely and correctly with the C++ string types will probably turn your hair grey.

Use the following typedef to create your string type that you can use throughout your code instead of std::string or std::wstring:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
```

Construct your string from the buffer directly:

```
tstring RealFileName(szTempFileName);
```